# How to pass form from a page with header as example.com?a=100?

Tags: javascript, php

There is a form in `adminhome.php?action=addbook` named `addbook`

```
<form name="addbook" action="adminhome.php?action=addbook" method="get" onsubmit="validatenumber();">
     Code:<br/><input type="text" name="code" ><br/>
     Class:<br/><input type="number" name="class" id="class1"><br/>
     title:<br/><input type="text" name="title"><br/>
     price:<br/><input type="number" name="price" id="price"><br/>
     quantity:<br/><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity"><br/>
     category:<br/><input type="text" name="category"><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"><br/>
 </form>
```

What should be the correct action in the form action attribute given below?

```
action="adminhome.php?action=addbook&addbook.php"
```

Actually when I submit form it is not getting validated.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validatenumber(){
        var class1=document.getElementByName("class")[0];
        if(parseInt(class1.value, 10) < 0){
            alert("Please enter positive integer");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it is a little unclear what you want. You want to pass some extra parameters with the URL, is this correct?

Comment: the url in action is not a valid one. What are you trying to do? Why don't you just use input filed with type hidden to pass all the parameters you want without displaying in dom?

Comment: @Elzo Valugi Yes I want to pass some extra parameters but already in my URL there are parameters. How to pass form values as extra URL?

Comment: I think you are just trying to use get method?

Comment: Use ampersand to add more parameters ex: index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form name="addbook" action="adminhome.php" method="get" onsubmit="validatenumber();">
     Code:<br/><input type="text" name="code" ><br/>
     Class:<br/><input type="number" name="class" id="class1"><br/>
     title:<br/><input type="text" name="title"><br/>
     price:<br/><input type="number" name="price" id="price"><br/>
     quantity:<br/><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity"><br/>
     category:<br/><input type="text" name="category"><br/>
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addbook">
     <input type="submit" value="submit"><br/>
 </form>
```

That would make all of the form inputs and the action available in the $_GET[] global in file adminhome.php

Comment: All parameters are available in gloabl file but when I give negative input it is not getting validated

Comment: Negative input? you mean submiting a price lower than 0?

Comment: class<0. How to validate that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4jba0dsx/

You have to prevent the form from submitting and then manually submit it with javascript using the submit() function

Comment: Actually action should be `addbook.php` it should move to that page

Comment: I guess so... the question is actually pretty confusing

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wvapgjs6/1/) versus [link2](https://jsfiddle.net/5ad5raq3/1/) both are giving different answers. I used ID in the first one which is not validating correctly. Can you give the reason?

Comment: Have you looked at my fiddle?

That works, just put your validating logic inside de javascript addEventListener callback function